# Angular component has click listener attribute

Tags: angular

How can I know within my-component, if the parent listens to the click event (A) or not (B).

Case A:

```html
<my-component (click)="onClick()"></my-component>
```

Case B:

```html
<my-component></my-component>
```

Definition:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {
  @???()
  hostHasClickListener: boolean;   // I want to know this within my component
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: check event emitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an `@Output` with `click` as the name. This forces the consumers to bind their function to this `click` when they use `(click)="Blah()"` in the HTML.

`this.click.observed` return `true` when `click` is used in the HTML.

##### mycomponent.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  public click = new EventEmitter();
  
  private _hasClick = false;

  public ngOnInit() {
     
     this._hasClick = this.click.observed;

     if(this._hasClick) {
       // do something here.
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: For RxJS prior v7, the check is: `this.click.observers.length > 0`. see linked post of this duplication.

Comment: Showcase example: https://angular-ivy-bh4jux.stackblitz.io